# DWR 3.0.2-RELEASE not work on wildfly + reverseAjax

Tags: javascript, java, push, dwr, reverse-ajax

I get this error (chrome console):

```
engine.js:1691 
POST http://localhost:9090/context-path/$%7BoverridePath%7D$%7BplainCallHandlerUrl%7D__System.checkHeartbeat.dwr 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ engine.js:1691
send2 @ engine.js:1561
send @ engine.js:1525
dwr.engine.endBatch @ engine.js:279
dwr.engine._execute @ engine.js:694
(anonymous) @ engine.js:818
```

This is the Clock Demo get from http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/downloads/index.html

This happens when i try to execute Clock.html the piece of code within window.onload fuction

What happens?

My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
          </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxWaitAfterWrite</param-name>
            <param-value>500</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowScriptTagRemoting</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>    
        <!-- Disables DWR's CSRF protection -->
        <init-param>
          <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
          <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks